# Android Webview Remember the account password

Tags: android

Android webview How to remember the account password when the user logs in?
I need to automatically fill in the account password the next time I enter the login screen.

Comment: Two steps: 1) Save the password into the sharedpreference. 2) when the page is loaded(`onPageFinished`) use javascript code to append the password into the password field

Comment: Use cookies https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager